# setting a delegate to self's delegate?

Tags: objective-c, ios, delegates

i have three ViewControllers; A, B, and C.

A presents B, B presents C.

how can i pass data from C back to A?

i set B's delegate to A.

```
BViewController *bvc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"B"];
bvc.delegate = self;
```

Can i set C's delegate to A somehow?

like:

```
CViewController *cvc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"C"];
cvc.delegate = (self's parent delegate)
```

?

or do i need to set C's delegate to B, then be to A?

Comment: I think you have some issues with your code/logic there.  `bvc.delegate = (self's parent delegate)` does not make sense, it should just be `bvc.delegate = self`...if I understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: bvc.delegate = (self's parent delegate) was just how i tried to express it. self would be View Controller B, and B's was modal presented by A so the parent would be View Controller A.

Answer (score 2):

Have viewcontroller C set its delegate to B; B sets its delegate A.  There now can be a method on B called sendMessageToA:  So at the point C sends its delegate the 'sendMessageToA' then B can send what ever data it needs to A.

Or you can just forward messages from B to A.  So C will send its delegate (B in this case) a message.  B says "I don't know this message, let me forward it." B sends the message to A.

this link does a good job of explaining the concept: http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2009-03-27-objective-c-message-forwarding.html

Answer (score 0):

You can most certainly set c's delegate to a or b. You have to decide if bypassing b is valid. b may want to do things before the message gets back to a, or it may not care. So, if you are instantiating c inside of b:

```
// make b the delegate of c
cvc.delegate = self;
```

or

```
// bypass b and make a the delegate of c
cvc.delegate = self.delegate;
```

c simply needs to know that whoever its delegate is, they can respond to the appropriate selector:

```
// in c
if ([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(doSomething)])
{
    [delegate doSomething];
}
```

EDIT FOR COMMENT BELOW:
Instead of making the delegate specific to the controller you could make a more generic protocol that describes the delegate:

```
@protocol InfoSelectorDelegate 
- (void)viewController:(UIViewController *)viewController didSelectInfo:(NSDictionary *)info 
@end
```

And then both delegates would be of type:

```
id<InfoSelectorDelegate>
```

Comment: I tried this but get a warning: Assigning to 'id<CDelegate>' from incompatible type 'id<BDelegate>'. Both A and B have C's delegate declared: @interface CViewController : UIViewController <CDelegate>

Comment: ok, why is the delegate method is taking in a UIViewController? also, do i just declare this protocol in each view controller? i'm don't quite follow how to sett this up.

Comment: No, you declare the protocol in a single place and then import it in the files that need to use or implement it. The view controller is in the delegate call so that the delegate can make decisions based on who sent the call. View controller A may want to do something different if the call came from B or C. It can check the value of viewController to determine where the call came from.